# Escape single quotes in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the following text for the `<span>` tag. How do I escape the single quotes for the following?

```
$("#spn_err").text($('#txt1').attr('value')+" is not valid");
```

I want to display the message as '`ZZZ' is not valid`. Here `$('#txt1').attr('value')` is a dynamic value. It may have `abc`, `bcc`, `ddd`, `zzz`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("#spn_err").text("'" + $('#txt1').val() + "' is not valid");
```

Inside double quotes, single quotes are normal characters and vice versa. Otherwise you can escape them by prepending a backslash: `"\""` or `'\''`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#spn_err").text('\'' + $("#txt1").attr("value") + '\' is not valid');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is close. Use the [`.val()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Val) method:

```
$('#spn_err').text($('#txt1').val() + ' is not valid');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#spn_err").text("'" + $('#txt1').attr('value') + "' is not valid");
```