# Escape single quote jQuery HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function calling a PHP class which should return the code in $var.
Because of the single quotes in the $var string, JavaScript keeps giving back an error.

What would be the best way to send code with ajax without worrying about the characters and the number of lines in the code?

```
$var = ' <span onclick="propMove(\'54957_363807.jpg\',\'7242\',\'right\');" class="badge badge-grey" style="float:right;margin:5px;cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span> ';

<script>   $("#container .content").html(' <?=json_encode($picsIn)?>  ');    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape single quotes in jQuery or JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083646/escape-single-quotes-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: The ajax code is working just fine if I would want to fill the target with the desired code. The thing is that I am telling the ajax to run a code which is filling other containers.

Comment: Why do you wrap static HTML into a variable in the first place?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? What part of the code you gave is PHP and what is Javascript?

Comment: The code is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$var = htmlentities($var);
```

This will return everything as html characters, and will not contain quotes.

In jQuery then do the following to the ajax response

```
function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
    var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
    return textArea.value;
}

var myCodeFromPHP = decodeEntities(myAjaxResponse);
```

Where "myCodeFromPHP" is the clean proper HTML, and "myAjaxResponse" is the htmlentities response

Hopefully this helps